# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable error in laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, instanceof

I’m building a carpool app where its the intention that when a user registers they’re able to fill in they have a car however this car is in a table on its own.

When I try to create it with the field `checkt` I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Cars given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/carpool-app-going-your-way/www/vendor/compiled.php on line 2078 and defined

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here is my code:

**registrar.php**

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    if (isset($_POST["ihaveacar"])){

        return Cars::create([
            'seats'=>$data['seats'],
            'seats_taken'=>'0',


        ]);



    }

    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'screen_name' => $data['screen_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'route' => $data['route'],
        'state' => $data['state'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'license_since' => $data['license_since'],
    ]);

}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;



class User extends model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract{

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'screen_name', 'email', 'password', 'birthday', 'license_since', 'kilometers', 'state', 'route','image','description','soft_delete', 'is_admin'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];



    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deletec_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];



}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** all of a sudden it seems to be running without errors. I don’t get it.

Comment: You should _not_ be using the `$_POST` super-global. Instead, retrieve data from the `Request` instance: http://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: the request instance doesnt work that well in my case i tried to use it when a user changes it profile as well and it kept failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an instance of `App\Cars` to the registrar via the `create()` method. Remove all non-login logic from the registrar and only perform said logic *after* the authentication logic is actually complete.

Comment: so if i remove the logic where should i put it then just after the create user in the same file or a totally different file all together ?

thanks for your response ;)

Comment: totally different file. Ur mixing up Authentication into the Application with the actual Application logic itself...that's messy. Keep it simple. After a "user" is authenticated redirect them to a different controller that will handle anything else

Answer (score 1):

you should extend  Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User 
like

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as AuthUser;
class Member extends AuthUser
{
    public  $table='members';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'password','qq','phone'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re returning two different object types in your `create()` method. If the request has a parameter called `ihaveacar` then you return a `Car` instance, otherwise you return a `User` instance. You need to make your mind up what your `create()` method should actually return.

Comment: actually he should do both when i have a sure i want to create a car thats gonna be to the user by a FK so that we later now what car belongs to that user and how meany seat it has in function of a carpooll app